# iPad app landscape launches root view controller with portrait dimension

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I have setup a new iPad project to only support UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight.

In my App Delegate I add a RootViewController to the window's rootViewController.

In this UIViewController (RootViewController) I have the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I have also tried with:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

However, I am not able to get the correct dimensions for my app when I create and add subviews based on the dimensions of my view controller's view.

If I output self.view.frame for my view controller I get `{{0, 0}, {768, 1024}}`, but I would like {1024, 768} instead. If I can't when are the dimensions correct so I can create my views with them in mind?

Sorry if this has been asked a billion times, I've browsed lots of SO questions, but nothing has solved my issue.

Comment: You're setting a `RootViewController` instance to `window.rootViewController`, right? Not a `UITabBarController` or anything wrapping it, right?

Answer (score 5):

I was running into the same issue, and what Ash Furrow said above seems to be correct; the orientation is set *after* `viewDidLoad` is called.

I was creating an iPad app that works in all orientations, but only the portrait orientations were getting set up correctly in my root UIViewController. In order to make the views layout correctly in landscape, I had to make sure the autoresizing masks on all my subviews was set to allow the view to adjust to landscape behind the scenes before being displayed to the user.

For example, I had a UIImageView that was the same size as the UIViewController's UIView. In order to get it to adjust correctly when rotating to landscape:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];    
backgroundImageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

Now the UIViewController can be configured in portrait orientation in the `viewDidLoad` method and rotate nicely to the portrait orientation before being displayed to the user.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

Looks like the interface orientation is being set already in `viewDidLoad`

```
p (UIInterfaceOrientation)[self interfaceOrientation]
(UIInterfaceOrientation) $1 = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

Here's my theory: interfaces on the iPad are, by default, 1024x768 if that have a status bar, which yours does. I believe that, even though the interface orientation is correct, it's not updating the view geometry until after `viewDidLoad`. I believe it has a very good reason for that.

If you look at the [`UIViewController` Life Cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1) docs, `viewDidLoad` is called as part of the set up of the view controller. *After* the view is loaded, `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: duration:` is called to let your view controller know it's geometry is changing.

It's not so much an answer as an explanation. Hopefully this will help you architect a solution to get around this problem.

### Begin answer that doesn't actually work:

In the `info.plist` for your project, open the "Supported Interface Orientations" option and delete the interface orientations you don't want to support. By default, all are supported:

[image: Supported Interface Orientations]

That should clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution: the Apple default app templates work with XIBs for the main view controller. To solve your problem just open the main viewcontroller XIB and set orientation to "landscape".

As I usually don't use XIBs and create all UI elements programmatically. That's why I had the same problem in previous projects that really drove me crazy. I then solved it by hard-coding the frame width & height value - not the nice way.